# ¿Cómo puedo aplicar los cambios a un solo botón y no todos a la vez? - Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy relizando una app en Angular, en esta tengo un `<div>` el cual itero para que se pueda repetir con info enviada desde Firebase, este contiene un `<button>` que cambia de color con `[ngClass]`y texto una vez se realice el click.
Aquí el codigo de HTML:

```
<div class="orders">
  <div class="order1" *ngFor="let orders of order$|async">
    <p>{{orders.orderNum}}</p>
    <div class="productsChefDiv">
    <p class="productsChef">{{orders.products}}</p>
    </div>
    <p>{{time}}</p>
    <button [ngClass]="{'pending': status, 'done': !status}" (click)="changeStatus(orders)">{{text}}</button>
  </div>
```

La función que implemente es:

```
changeStatus(orders): void {
            this.status = !this.status;
            if (!this.status) {
                  this.text = 'Done';
            } else {
                  this.text = 'Pending';
            }
      }
```

Pero, este cambio se aplica a todos los botones y no solo al botón clickeado. ¿Cómo puedo lograr que solo aplique al botón que doy click y no todos?. No he logrado encontrar la solución y es mi primer proyecto con Angular

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes hacer que `status` sea un propiedad de `orders` para que sea independiente para cada botón.

```
 <button class="buttons" [ngClass]="{'pending': orders.status, 'done': !orders.status}" 
(click)="changeStatus(orders)">{{text}}</button>
```

Y en la función `changeStatus` se cambia el estado para ese objeto:

```
changeStatus(orders): void {
    orders.status = !orders.status;
    orders.text = orders.status ? 'Pending' : 'Done';
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo implementaré y cualquier cosa estare comentando

Comment: añadiendo el status como propiedad del objeto funcionó a pesar de que perdí el texto que tenía el botón por default